# How to align buttons vertically

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Hi guys I have a few radio buttons that I want vertical, but I can only seem to get the horizontal.

Currently my code is:

```
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="{formBean.number}">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 - 19" itemValue="1" /> 
                    <!-- Add in the help button by the side of each item once its lined up, use a grid ?
                    <p:button icon="ui-icon-help" title="Help">  
                    </p:button> -->
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="20 - 39" itemValue="2" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="40 - 49" itemValue="4" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="50 - 59" itemValue="5" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="60 - 69" itemValue="6" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="70 - 79" itemValue="7" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="80 - 100" itemValue="8" />  
                </p:selectOneRadio>  
            </p:panelGrid>
```

How can I change it from horizontal to vertical, I have tried the grid way but still the same.

Thanks guys

EDIT

i have now achieved what i set out :

```
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="{formBean.number}" layout="grid" columns="1" required = "True"
                              requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredGender}"> 
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 - 19" itemValue="1" /> 

                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="20 - 39" itemValue="2" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="40 - 49" itemValue="4" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="50 - 59" itemValue="5" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="60 - 69" itemValue="6" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="70 - 79" itemValue="7" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="80 - 100" itemValue="8" />  
                </p:selectOneRadio>  
            </p:panelGrid>
```

only issue is now the grid is the size of the page, any way this can be aligned to left and made only the size of the labes ?

Comment: Try wrapping each radio in a block element like div or p or label.

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly html as you used the tags, can you copy the html and CSS to a fiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `layout` attribute on `p:selectOneRadio` with value `pageDirection`.

Here are possible values for `layout`:

- `lineDirection` - For Horizontal Direction
- `pageDirection` - For Vertical direction.
- `grid` - For a grid pattern
- `pageDirection` - For Vertical direction.
- `responsive` - For dynamically using the space provided
- `custom` - For custom Layout.

[Example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml)